# Typescript: adding type definition to Observable.of(null)

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

In my program I have a method that can return either an observable of `MyClass` or `Observable.of(null)`.
The code is along the following lines:

```
doSomething(someParams) {    
      return this.backEnd.getStuff(someParams)
                    .switchMap(data => {
                        if (!data ) {
                            return Observable.of(null);
                        } else {
                            this.doSomethingElse(data);
                        }
                    });
}
```

where doSomethingElse() returns an `Observable<MyClass>`.

If I code the method as above, I loose intellisense since my IDE (VSCode) tells me that the method doSomething() returns an Observable.

Is there a way to maintain intellisense in such a case? What I would like to have is the IDE suggesting me that the method doSomething() returns an `Observable<MyClass>` and naturally have my logic check is there is actually an instance of `MyClass` or `null` when the result is subscribed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type your return type as `Observable<MyClass | null>` where `MyClass | null` is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types):

```
doSomething(someParams): Observable<MyClass | null> {
   // ...
}
```